# Can i duplicate this Hallway then join it on end of current hall at a 45deg angle as a continuous (short video of render in post)?

Tags: objects, edit-mode, vertices

Im new to Blender (and modeling), sorry if im not using the correct terminology.

*Here is the render/model in question:*
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLf0lAGD8WM

I created this hall following Ducky 3D's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwFGNNbNMvg how-to. It has a few cubes and some NurbsPath's.

I would like to make a copy of current hall and place that copy on the end at a 45deg angle (or 90deg). Ive tried this by placing the copy at the end having the outer corners touching each other so there is no gaps, then tried to use the knife tool ( K ) and cut out the over lapping inner walls. It worked to a degree, but does not seam like the correct way to do this. Also tried to add a Boolean Modifier, but could not get that to work at all.

Any help or proper keywords i can use to search with would be great...

Using Blender 2.8

Here's a link to the hallway: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLf0lAGD8WM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you could do it.

Duplicate the hallway, select the duplicate, go into edit mode, select this face:
[image: active face]

and then press A to select all faces. This is now the active face.

Change your snap settings to Vertex and make sure Active and Move are selected.

[image: snap settings]

Press G and then X or Y depending on how the hallway is aligned, then either press CTRL if snapping is disabled or enable snapping with shift+tab. Drag the duplicate hallway until it snaps to the original hallway.

[image: snap]

Press 2 to go into edge select mode, select the edge pictured below, and press shift+s, the choose Cursor to Selected.

[image: cursor to selected]

Change your pivot point to 3D Cursor.

[image: pivot point]

Change snapping back to increment and rotate the duplicate hallway around Z by 45 or 90 or whatever degrees.

[image: rotate]

Now you have lots of options. Here are two. In object mode select both hallways and then go into edit mode. Select the inner edge loops of the hallways and select Bridge Edge Loops from the right-click menu or from the Edge menu dropdown. Do the same for the outer loops.

[image: bridge edge loops]

Alternatively, you could use the spin tool.

[image: spin tool]

You could add additional offsets to the hallways to make the curve more gradual, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and the walk through you have provided.
I worked my way through your instructions, but got hung up on the last step: "Select the inner edge loops of the hallways and select Bridge Edge Loops from the right-click menu or from the Edge menu dropdown". Im having a hard time selecting a loop. Im going to re-try this later, but wanted to say thank you for the help.

Comment: Go into edge select mode (2 on keyboard in edit mode), hold ctrl and left click on an edge of the edge loop you want to select. It should grab the entire loop as long as there are no vertices with poles. Select the opposing edge loop by holding shift+ctrl and clicking on an edge of the other loop. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again, @Electric_Wizard. Im still having issues selecting the loops. Ive screen recorded the process you posted here as i tried it. Im gonna try this at a later time with a simple hollowed out cube and see if i can get through it.
Here's a video of where im stuck...
https://youtu.be/C7PdsXpW44A?t=200
Again thanks, even though im still stumped, learned alot from your post.

Comment: Thanks again, Electric_Wizard.
I was able to get the Spin Tool to work. Before going back to your suggestion i tried (successfully) a different approach with Mirror Modifier found here: https://blenderartists.org/t/can-i-duplicate-a-hallway-join-on-end-of-current-hall-at-45deg-as-a-continuous-render-in-post/1206187

Final out come a bit sloppy (my own doing), but posting final render in-case others can learn from these posts.
Out come, the first corner is done with Mirror Modifier at a 45deg, second corner with Spin Tool.
Final result: https://youtu.be/4gQE8gPcMJA

Thanks again.